# MSgraph, takes up to 48 hours before changes are visible

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We use MSgraph and EWS API for our products.
When we do changes in our test Microsoft 365 environment (Add/change/delete - roomlists and rooms) we see the changes immediately when testing with EWS Editor.
But it takes up to 48 hours before we se the changes by using MSgraph Explorer.
I would guess that this is not expected behavior?

**We understand it might take some time (Up to 30 minutes) but up to 48 hours?**

Our test environment is a pure Microsoft 365 tenant (No hybrid)
The MSgraph API calls we test is:

*GET /places/microsoft.graph.room* and *GET /places/microsoft.graph.roomlist*

It seems that this issue might have been introduced after our environment was moved to the Norwegian datacenter.

No error messages from MSgraph, all seems normal..

Here is the results from MSgraph when i ask for roomlist:

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#places/microsoft.graph.roomList",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "32d75744-113e-4bec-91c4-811623d11521",
        "displayName": "Test2",
        "address": null,
        "geoCoordinates": null,
        "phone": "",
        "emailAddress": "Test2@loop24.no"
    },
    {
        "id": "1d535e8b-c44d-498a-9046-dbbe1ae3be75",
        "displayName": "TestList",
        "address": null,
        "geoCoordinates": null,
        "phone": "",
        "emailAddress": "testlist@loop24.no"
    },
    {
        "id": "b9ea8bd6-32da-4d6d-b38e-db6c03f4fa54",
        "displayName": "RoomList",
        "address": null,
        "geoCoordinates": null,
        "phone": "",
        "emailAddress": "roomlist@loop24.no"
```

Here is the results from EWSEditor (This is correct)
Call Get Roomlist  roomlist@loop24.no  Roomlist

Comment: Tom, Do you just see the delay or any error you receive?

Comment: Also please share your response output of the above API call (response id or client request id, timestamp of the call) so that we can have a look at it. Outside of MS Graph explorer you may want to test the calls from the POSTMAN tool as well.

Comment: No error messages from MSgraph, all looks fine except that the data is old..
It takes up to 48 hours before my changes are visible in MSgraph.

Comment: I've updated the description with data from the MSgraph and EWS calls.

Comment: (1) I tried locally but i failed to repro the issue with my test bed. Both Graph Explorer and EWS Editor works for me and pulls the correct data (2) I dont see any detailed response above (which will contain client request id, timestamp of the call) from the Graph API call; so that we can cross check. (3) Also you can consider opening Microsoft Support ticket (from your Microsoft Office 365 Portal) so that it can be handled by Microsoft Tech Support as well.

Comment: To reproduce the issue: Try to add/delete a rescource or roomlist in 365 Tenant, then see the results you get from EWS and MSgraph. It takes 24-48 hours before the change is propogated to MSgraph. I also suspect it has something to do with the fact that our 0365 tenant is in the Norwegian datacenter I raised a support issue but the case was closed since i did not have premium support. (Basically they did not even care to investigate)